# Stripe differentiation between charge deduction and Subscription assignment in webhook upon charge.succeeded

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am struggling for this for two days, I want to differentiate between subscription assignment and manually deducting the charge from Stripe. charge.succeeded webhook is called both times. In webhook call, I need to differentiate between Subscription assignment and Charge deduction for a particular amount.

Subscription Assignment is using below code.

```
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
                                                "customer" => $customer_id,
                                                "plan" => $stripe_plan_id,
                                                ));
```

And charge deduction is using below code.

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                                                'amount' => $price ,
                                                'currency' => 'usd',
                                                'customer' =>  $customer_id
                                                    )
                                    );
```

If anyone has any idea please suggest the way. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon receiving the [`charge.succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-charge.succeeded) event, you can extract the [charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object) and check the charge's [`invoice`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-invoice) attribute:

```
// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);

if ($event_json->type == "charge.succeeded") {
    $charge = $event_json->data->object;

    if ($charge->invoice == null) {
        // One-off charge
    } else {
        // Subscription charge
    }
}
```

Note that technically, a charge can be linked to an invoice but not to a subscription, in case you [created an invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoice) manually. If you need to distinguish in this case, you'll need to use the invoice's ID to [retrieve the invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_invoice), and check the invoice's [`subscription`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object-subscription) attribute to see if it's `null` or not.

Comment: Thanks Mate, I am able to do this by using invoice check. It helps a lot !!